Site user survey?
This is a follow-on to a question posted earlier here:
Physics site-wide metrics on things like question closure/deletion rates etc?
Based on some helpful information that was provided, I located a publicly available query to determine monthly question closure rates (as a first example of a potentially useful metric):  https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1181148/closed-question-rate#graph.  I don't know if the query is necessarily correct, but people are welcome to look at the SQL code and source databases to confirm.  However, assuming it is correct for the present discussion.
Here is an image of the results.

Taking a rough estimate, it looks like the average monthly closure rate is ~15%.  This translates to around 1-in-6 or 1-in-7 questions being closed.
This seems rather a high rate.  I can imagine this translating to a poor user experience, especially a new user who is possibly quite unfamiliar with the site protocols, and may not ever return after such an encounter.
It suggests to me that Stack Exchange may want to implement some type of survey system for users (first time and established) to see what the pain points are, if any.  This would be a great complement to the site analytics, towards any needed improvements/evolution of the site.  Having all the results public (i.e. irrespective of rep level) would be an excellent outcome.
Thank you.

This seems rather a high rate Compared to what? Also, 10k (20k?) moderator tools says in the last 30 days, it's closer to 40% close rate (850 of 2k questions) the bulk of which are either HW or Unclear.

It suggests to me that Stack Exchange may want to implement... feature requests should be asked on [meta.se], rather than this site's Meta

Yes, everyone who dumped their homework question on us is annoyed that it is not answered. I do not feel particularly sorry for them. Having a question closed as unclear is often accompanied by comments that may help the OP understand, should they chose to take them into account. Closed questions can be reopened.

@KyleKanos The query being used by OP isn't fully accurate as it is searching in Posts, which doesn't include deleted questions. A large portion of closed questions are deleted after 9 days of inactivity. The query will need to be amended to search in PostsWithDeleted.

To your “especially a new user who is possibly quite unfamiliar with the site protocols, and may not ever return after such an encounter”:

Surely the onus is on new users to absorb the site protocols before they post, else the quality of questions will plummet and the incentive for more experienced contributors to stick around will be removed.
Frankly, if new users are just in for a quick answer, or skip over due diligence and do not search the site for duplicates or near duplicates, then the best outcome is for them to discover quickly the site is not what they are looking for.
Over the years the site has maintained a reasonable level of quality and has attracted a steady flow of new users; granted the protocols are not the liking of some but they are clearly and certainly to the liking of very many others, as the traffic statistics shows.  Unless there is a compelling reason to make an abrupt change, why do so?

